# Try to decode random @Variant string from an android studio emulator

Tags: android, android-studio, emulation, android-virtual-device, avd-manager

Just a quick question ig. I am currently trying something with android studio's virtual devices and i need to edit a parameter in one of the emulator files.

The path to this file is normaly {HomeDir}\.android\avd\name_of_virtual_device.avd\AVD.conf

The content of the file looks like this:

```
[perAvd]
battery\charge_level=100
loc\latitude=37.422
virtualscene\posters=@Variant(\0\0\0\b\0\0\0\x2\0\0\0\b\0w\0\x61\0l\0l\0\0\0\n\0\0\0\xa0\0\x43\0:\0/\0U\0s\0\x65\0r\0s\0/\0M\0\x61\0x\0i\0m\0i\0l\0i\0\x61\0n\0\x42\0r\0\x61\0u\0n\0/\0P\0i\0\x63\0t\0u\0r\0\x65\0s\0/\0{\0\x36\0\x44\0\x37\0\x43\0\x30\0\x33\0\x37\0\x42\0-\0\x39\0\x34\0\x37\0\x43\0-\0\x34\0\x37\0\x33\0\x37\0-\0\x41\0\x44\0\x30\0\x41\0-\0\x45\0\x36\0\x41\0\x45\0\x43\0\x37\0\x37\0\x37\0\x43\0\x44\0\x34\0\x43\0}\0.\0p\0n\0g\0.\0j\0p\0g\0\0\0\n\0t\0\x61\0\x62\0l\0\x65\0\0\0\n\xff\xff\xff\xff)
virtualscene\tv_animation=false
loc\longitude=-122.084
loc\altitude=5
loc\velocity=0
loc\heading=0
```

If you know your way arround the avd manager of android studio and emulated devices you should note pretty quickly that this file contains some of the advanced settings that you normaly can set via the menu of your emulated device. Now my question is since i need to edit the `virtualscene\posters` param which encoding is this. I mean it looks like hex but it isn't. It also contains like `png/jpg` at the end of the string looking like this `.\0p\0n\0g\0.\0j\0p\0g`. But i cant figure out which encoding this is

Hope someone can help

Answer (score 0):

That looks like it is probably a [QSettings](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qsettings.html#Format-enum) configuration file. This class saves a program's settings to a `.conf` or `.ini` file and encodes data like that. It allows it to later read the data back in using [QVariant](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qvariant.html#details)